# Find the number that has the biggest square

Tags: sorting, racket

So I have to write a code where I give 3 numbers and the program should square the numbers and output the biggest result and so far I wrote this

```
(define (squared-max x y z)
  (cond (> (* x x) (and (* y y) (* z z)))(* x x)
        (else
         (cond (> (* y y) (* z z)) (* y y)
               (> (* z z) (* y y)) (* z z)))))
```

But when I run the code it only outputs the square of the last number no matter if it's the biggest or not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does squaring really have anything to do with the problem? Wouldn't the largest of x, y, and z also have the largest square? It would be simpler to just find the max of the numbers instead.

Comment: I don't know racket, but the number with the biggest square is also going to be the biggest input number, so that should help streamline things a bit.

Comment: Although, you'd want to probably get the absolute value of each first, but Racket likely has a built-in for that.

Comment: I did try to use (abs x) but the same thing happens, only now it just displays the last number without squaring it

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks kind of complex!  When things look complicated, it can be more difficult to just look at the code and see right away what's going wrong.

How could we make it simpler?  Well, one thing we could do is stop repeating ourselves so much.  We don't really need to square each variable over and over.  We could just do it once by splitting things up into two functions:

```
(define (squared-max x y z)
  (find-biggest (* x x)
                (* y y)
                (* z z)))

(define (find-biggest x y z)
  ...)
```

Once we do that, we can rewrite your function without all the squares, so we can focus on the "figure out which number is biggest" part.  Let's try:

```
(define (find-biggest x y z)
  (cond (> x (and y z)) x
        (else
         (cond (> y z) y
               (> z y) z))))
```

Oops, it still doesn't work!  But now that it's a little simpler, we can focus on *why* it doesn't work.  I spot three main problems here:

1. You're missing parens around each test–value pair.  Let's add those in:

   ```
   (define (find-biggest x y z)
     (cond ((> x (and y z)) x)
           (else
            (cond ((> y z) y)
                  ((> z y) z)))))
   ```

   We need those parens!  Without them, `(> x (and y z))` and `x` aren't grouped as a test and a value.  In your original code, `(> (* x x) (and (* y y) (* z z)))` and `(* x x)` were interpreted as two different tests for that reason, leading to some very confusing behavior.  But since it was just so complicated to look at, it was more difficult to read and spot this problem.
2. The comparison `(> x (and y z))` doesn't do what you want.  The `and` macro checks if any of the things you pass to it are false, but numbers are never false; instead, this code always ends up returning the last number you sent it, which is `z`.  So this boils down to `(> x z)`, which is not what you want.

   Instead, we could pull out the `and`:

   ```
   (and (> x y)
        (> x z))
   ```

   That's what you really wanted to say.  "Is X bigger than Y, and is X also bigger than Z?"
3. Your last `cond` is not exhaustive.  You check `> y z` and `> z y`, but what if they're the same number?  In that case returning either of them would be fine, but instead you return nothing at all.  Let's change the second test expression to an `else`:

   ```
   (define (find-biggest x y z)
     (cond ((and (> x y)
                 (> x z)) x)
           (else
            (cond ((> y z) y)
                  (else z)))))
   ```

Now it should all work okay.  You could rewrite the `cond`s with `if`s if you like:

```
(define (find-biggest x y z)
  (if (and (> x y)
           (> x z))
      x
      (if (> y z)
          y
          z)))
```

But it'll work fine with `cond`, too, so that's just a matter of personal taste.  I like it with `if` because I feel like it's a little bit easier to read and understand.

As an aside, some of the comments suggested using `abs`, but that's not really a good idea.  Yes, it's true that `(abs x)` is ordered in the same way as `(* x x)`, but we want to end up with the square, not the absolute value, so even though we *could* write `abs`, we *shouldn't* because it makes it less obvious what we're doing to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into racket, part of the problem seems to stem from your use of `and`. The way `and` works with numerics is it will return `#f` if any of the arguments passed to it are`#f`, otherwise it will return the right-most argument. In the case of `(> x (and y z))`, the inner expression will always return `z` (assuming `y` and `z` are not `#f`) which boils down to the expression `(> x z)`.

Another part of the problem is that, on your second `cond`, you haven't marked the final expression with `else`. The cursory understanding that I have isn't enough to say what that actually causes to happen, but my guess is that, since you don't have an `else` body, all the expressions in that `cond` are getting executed in order, which results in the return value being the result of the final expression (which, in this case, is `* z z`).

This is my humble pass at a naive attempt. I'm sure there's a better way to do this with loops and more intelligent dynamic comparisons, but this gets the job done in a brute-force sort of way.

```lisp
(define (squared-max x y z)
    (cond
        [(>= (abs x) (abs y) (abs z)) (* x x)]
        [(>= (abs x) (abs z) (abs y)) (* x x)]
        [(>= (abs y) (abs x) (abs z)) (* y y)]
        [(>= (abs y) (abs z) (abs x)) (* y y)]
        [(>= (abs z) (abs x) (abs y)) (* z z)]
        [(>= (abs z) (abs y) (abs x)) (* z z)]
    )
)
```

---

Of course, assuming you don't have to do the comparisons yourself as part of the assignment, an alternative approach would be to just use `max`:

```lisp
(define (squared-max x y z)
    (max (* x x) (* y y) (* z z))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the posted code. Correct indentation will help make the problems visible. Looking at the first conditional clause, you can see that `>` is the test expression, and the expressions `(* x x)` and `(and (* y y) (* z z))` are to be evaluated when `>` is true (which is always, since only `#f` is not a true value in schemes):

```
(define (squared-max x y z)
  (cond (>
         (* x x)
         (and (* y y) (* z z)))
        (* x x)
        (else
         (cond (>
                (* y y)
                (* z z))
               (* y y)
               (>
                (* z z)
                (* y y))
               (* z z)))))
```

The `cond` form takes conditional clauses, each of which is comprised of a test expression optionally followed by a number of expressions which are evaluated if the test evaluates to true. In the posted code, the first conditional clause has `>` as the test expression; this *always* evaluates as true. Instead the test expression should be something like `(> (* x x) (* y y))`.

Further complicating matters, OP has `(and (* y y) (* z z))`; it seems that OP may intend something along the lines of `(and (> (* x x) (* y y)) (> (* y y) (* z z)))`. But due to the nature of the `and` special form, `(and (* y y) (* z z))` will *always* evaluate to `(* z z)`.

So, the posted definition for `squared-max` returns the result of evaluating `(* z z)` every time it is called because: 1) `>` evaluates as true in the first conditional clause; 2) `(and (* y y) (* z z))` evaluates to `(* z z)`; 3) `cond` returns the value of evaluating the last expression of the selected conditional clause.

Here is a fixed-up version that corrects the errors mentioned above:

```
(define (squared-max x y z)
  (cond ((and (> (* x x) (* y y))
              (> (* y y) (* z z)))
         (* x x))
        ((> (* x x) (* y y))
         (* z z))
        ((> (* y y) (* z z))
         (* y y))
        (else
         (* z z))))
```

You could also write this using `if` instead of `cons`. Note that `if` does not have conditional clauses; it has a test, a single expression to be evaluated if the test evaluates to true, and another single expression to be evaluated if the test fails:

```
(define (squared-max x y z)
  (if (> (* x x) (* y y))
      (if (> (* x x) (* z z))
          (* x x)
          (* z z))
      (if (> (* z z) (* y y))
          (* z z)
          (* y y))))
```